# Performance testing for MS Windows desktop applications

Tags: tools, performance, windows

Could you recommend any tools for testing performance of desktop applications running on MS Windows? I would like to verify the speed of application activities versus HW and OS configuration. I have to perform tests on several HW desktops and and Win7, Win8, XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some performance testing you don't need a specific tool, only a **well-designed test case set**, a bunch of test suites which with some variables can be used on any type of operating system family.

When you design the test cases, you should take in consideration the application's **requirements** and **non-functionalities**:

- how many users will use the application in the same time?
- Does it have a network connection?
- How should the application behave if the network is working very
  slowly?
- And what if it receives too many requests?
- How should be the system configured for the application's optimized
  work?
- What time-requirements are necessary  (response time, timed-out
  requests)? And so on.

You may need for some performance testing types some simple tools, but they are not very complicated. For a **load testing** for example you can even use the windows' build-in tool, the Task Manager, to monitor the processes' behavior. As Tom77 said in his comment, sometimes even a stopwatch is enough, but ensure you make notes in a table to compare them at the end, and you are testing the right functionality of the application.

I think, the key is the test cases' correctness and portability. For this I can suggest the **Microsoft's Test Manager**, if you are already a Windows user. It isn't the best tool, quite buggy, but it can be easily integrated with other Agile tools, such as Workbench and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Please review my article: [Performance Testing of Desktop Applications](http://united.softserveinc.com/blog/automated-performance-testing-desktop-app/).
Also, check full description of the solution in [pdf](http://united.softserveinc.com/getattachment/blogs/united-blog/August-2015/automated-performance-testing-desktop-app/Automated-Performance-Testing-of-Desktop-Applications.pdf/)

Comment: Could you please provide some extracted information and not only a link.

Comment: There is an open source tool Alyvix (or Al'exa):   http://www.alyvix.com,  which allows to test performance of the desktop applications using image/text recognition approach. For example, your script clicks on some button by image and then you wait for some Window's dialog or another control, so Alyvix allows to track time/resources utilization during these operations. By default it has integration with Nagios. In my solution I have integrated it with Windows Perfromance Monitor. More description can be found in pdf file above under the link